# Error: cordova platform add browser

Tags: cordova, npm

```
> cordova create MyApp2
> cd MyApp2
> cordova platform add browser
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
> cordova -v
7.0.1
> node -v
v8.1.0
> npm -v
5.0.3
```

While executing this command `cordova platform add browser` I get **Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'**. What is wrong?

Comment: ,chen need more info like windows or ios? which version of npm are you using?

Comment: in IOS version 10.12.5,npm version 5.0.3

Comment: Can you share the plugins that you have added to the project?